# Struggling in zend acl system

Tags: zend-framework, acl

I am new to zend framework and trying to implement zend_acl.I created a custom plugin and placed it in

- zend/library/My/Controller/Plugin
- zend/library/My/Controller/Helper

where myzend is directory of my project.I am trying to initialize this custom plugin from
bootstrap using

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$frontController->setControllerDirectory('/path/to/controllers')
                ->setRouter(new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite())
                ->registerPlugin(new My_Controller_Plugin_Acl());
```

But i am receiving this error message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Action_Exception' with message 'Action  index" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()' in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php:485 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(518): Zend_Controller_Action->__call('indexAction', Array) 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(308): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\public\index.php(44): Zend_Application->run() 
#6 {main} Next exception 'Zend_Controller_Exception' with message 'Action "index" does not exist and in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 336
```

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error does not look like its related to Plugins. Are you sure everything works OK if you remove those two lines?

Comment: Yes, When I comment $frontController variables the errors are disapperad. Errors found in these two lines $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$frontController->setControllerDirectory('/path/to/controllers')
                ->setRouter(new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite())
                ->registerPlugin(new My_Controller_Plugin_Acl());

Comment: Is that your plugin extends of Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract?

Comment: Yes. the plugin extends of Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract.

Comment: Have you a redirection in a postdispatch() method in your plugin?

Comment: No. I wrote preDispatch() function only in my plugin.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was mistaken :). In your "preDispatch", how is your redirection?

Comment: `public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
  $acl = Zend_Registry::get('acl');
  $usersNs = new Zend_Session_NameSpace('members');
   If($usersNs->userType==''){
    $roleName='guest';
   } else {
    $roleName=$userType;
   }
  $privilageName=$request->getActionName();
  if(!$acl->isAllowed($roleName,null,$privilageName)) {
   $request->setControllerName('Error');
   $request->setActionName('index');
  }
 }`

Comment: Have you an `indexAction` method in your `ErrorController`? 
It would not rather `errorAction`?

Comment: The redirection is `if(!$acl->isAllowed($roleName,null,$privilageName)) { $request->setControllerName('Error'); $request->setActionName('index'); }`

Comment: I have `errorAction` method only in my `ErrorController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your redirection in your preDispatch() method, try this :

```
$request->setActionName('error');
```

Instead of:

```
$request->setActionName('index');
```

If you want make an error try this:

```
throw new Zend_Acl_Exception("Not allowed");
```

instead of

```
$request->setControllerName('Error'); 
$request->setActionName('index');
```

Comment: @Manikandan : I add a solution in my answer

Comment: The `errorAction` method did not get the getParam objects `$errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');`

Comment: Is someone can explain the reason for the down vote? :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your Plugin in `library/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php` and then add this in your application (Bootstrap suggested).

```
//register your folder with aoutloader
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace('My_');

//register your plugin
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$frontController->registerPlugin(new My_Controller_Plugin_Acl());
```

Your code changed default Controller directory so Zend could not find proper Action

Comment: Did you removed `->setControllerDirectory('/path/to/controllers')` and ` ->setRouter(new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite())`?